# Spark application dependency version vs Spark server version

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a simple question about using Spark, which although most tools usually explain this question explicitly (in important text, such as a specific format or a separate page), I did not find it anywhere. Maybe my search was not enough, but I thought it was good that I ask this question in the hope that maybe the answer will benefit other people as well.

Spark binary is usually downloaded from the following link and installed and configured on the cluster: [Download Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

If, for example, we use the Java language for programming (although it can be other supported languages), we need the following dependencies to communicate with Spark:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As is clear, both the Spark cluster (binary of Spark) and the dependencies used on the application side have a specific version. In my opinion, it is obvious that if the version used is the same on both the application side and the server side, everything will most likely work in its ideal state without any problems.

But the question is, what if the two versions are not the same? Is it possible to have compatibility between the server and the application in specific number of conditions (such as not changing major version)? Or, for example, if the client is always ahead, is it not a problem? Or if the server is always ahead, is it not a problem?

Unfortunately, I did not find the answer to any of these cases! Because it is difficult to use the same version due to the existence of libraries that may be updated late and are not in our control. I would be happy if anyone can provide its own experience or resources related to this.

### Update 1

I think something went wrong in the sense of the question. My argument is not that it is better to define a variable to make sure that the same version is used everywhere. (For example `${spark_version}`) The argument is that there may be a library that I did not write and it is an old version, but I want to update my cluster (server version). Or it may not be possible for me to update the server version and all the applications version at the same time, so I want to update each one separately. As a result, the application-server version differs in a period of time. (maybe short or long period) I want to know exactly how Spark works in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit risky… My Spark code is often full of static functions that may defer from version to version, even minor versions (and even in patch versions if I remember correctly, or at least some behavior may have changed).

Then it may defer between a job in Python and Java/Scala. You Spark-submit” the Python source code vs. byte code. It may work better with Python, but I would still not recommend it.

My experience also showed that in some previous versions of Spark where you could pick between Scala 2.11 and 2.12, the behavior would change.

In summary, with all the subtleties of Apache Spark, I would not try to mix and match versions, I would even recommend you log the version of Spark when you driver starts. In Maven, I always use variables to avoid potential issues with versions ([example of pom.xml](https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01/blob/master/pom.xml)).

Comment: I myself think it might be a problem if a feature is used that differs in the versions. But if we assume that a new or deleted feature is not used, then will there be a problem or not? There are many tools today that address the issue of backward and forward compatibility. It is even more strange to me that this case is not stated anywhere for Spark so that we can act with certainty instead of speculation.

Comment: It’s probably not documented because every time you have some creativity with versions it fails :). There’s probably a few good reasons around that specific points that Databricks decided to rewrite Spark in C++. 
If you look at the number of dependencies with Spark (all the JARs), you will see the “dark side” of dependencies. That too may affect your apps.

Comment: Just added a link to a standard POM I am using with Spark using versions: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Because I thought there was a misconception about the reason for the question, I did an update on the question.